# HowTo: Access client.mutate method from Apollo? Refactoring from 1.9.2 to 2.4.2

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

OS: Windows 10 Pro
apollo-boost: "^0.1.16"
apollo-client: "^2.4.2"

Does anyone know how to access the `client.mutate` method from Apollo now? I wish to do the following:

```html
  client.mutate({
      mutation: REMOVE_FROM_CART_MUTATION,
      variables: {
         cartItem.id,
      },
  })
  .catch(this.handleSubmitError);

....
withApollo(CartItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using React, you can import `withApollo` like so:

```
import { withApollo } from 'react-apollo';
```

then make sure to wrap the component (I do this on export):

`export default withApollo(CartItem);`

By doing so, `ApolloProvider` will automatically inject the `client` to your props and you can access it from within the component by doing `this.props.client.mutate(...);` or `this.props.client.query(...);`

**NOTE:** this means your component *must* be a child of the `ApolloProvider` in your component tree. The Apollo docs recommend doing this at the highest level possible in your App, such as:

```
<ApolloProvider client={client}>
  <App />
</ApolloProvider>
```

You can find more information on using the query and mutate APIs in the [Apollo API client reference](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client.html#ApolloClient.query).

If you're trying to interact directly with your local cache, you can find information on the `client.readyQuery()` and `client.writeQuery()` APIs in the [Apollo client GitHub repo](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/tree/master/packages/apollo-cache-inmemory#direct-cache-access).